# Named placeholders in with PDO mySQL causing server error

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm a novice when it comes to mySQL, and even more so when it comes to PDO.  I'm trying to create some simple insert code but I keep getting a server error.  I have a feeling it has to do with defining `$STH` twice.  Here's my code:

```
$dsn    = "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=Menu_Items";
$user   = "root";
$pass   = "root";

// Connect to database
try{
    $DBH = new pdo($dsn, $user, $pass);
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}

// Define user input as $food
$name = $_POST['food'];

$STH->bindParam(':name', $name);

// Insert user input into table
$STH = $DBH->prepare("INSERT INTO foods ( name ) VALUES ( :name )");

$result = $DBH -> query($STH);
if($result){
    echo("<br>Input data is succeed");
}else{
    echo("<br>Input data is fail");
}
```

This php code is connected to a simple html form:

```
<form id="menu_input" name="menu_input" method="post" action="insert.php">
      <table>
        <thead>Enter a new item</thead>
        <tr>
          <th><label for="food">Food</label></th>
          <td><input type="text" name="food" id="food" placeholder="Food Name" required></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><input type="submit"></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
 </form>
```

I've been doing research but just having a little difficulty getting it to work.  Thoughts?

Comment: bind should be after prep?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First create/get the object/instance then use its methods; not the other way round.

```
// Insert user input into table
$STH = $DBH->prepare("INSERT INTO foods ( name ) VALUES ( :name )");
$STH->bindParam(':name', $name);
$STH->execute();
```

and (nit-picking mode: on) there's no need for the variable `$name`

```
// Insert user input into table
$STH = $DBH->prepare("INSERT INTO foods ( name ) VALUES ( :name )");
$STH->bindValue(':name', $_POST['food']);
$STH->execute();
```

will do, and so would

```
// Insert user input into table
$STH = $DBH->prepare("INSERT INTO foods ( name ) VALUES ( :name )");
$STH->execute(array('name'=>$_POST['food']));
```

Comment: So the server error is gone, but now nothing is inserting into my table.  Any ideas?

Comment: Try it with `$DBH->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` right after the `$DBH = new pdo ...` line. This won't _fix_ anything, but in case of an error it's much harder for you to miss it ;-)

Comment: Oh, and btw: `$DBH -> query($STH)` is wrong. Reaplce it by `$STH->execute();`.

Answer (score 0):

Named placeholders has nothing to do with your problem.
And they aren't "best bet". It's just a syntax sugar, quite unnecessary one.

Your problem is not a named placeholder but syntax which you have got out of nowhere.

1. Always read the manual page on the function you are using. query() method doesn't support placeholders.
2. Always read [tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/pdo/info) before asking a question. There you can see the proper example.

Please read Stackoverflow tag wiki on PDO I linked above and use code from there. Both for connecting and query execution.
You have to set up error reporting to see the errors. Otherwise there is noway to know what is wrong with your code.

Comment: No need to down-vote. Using `->query($STH);` here _is_ wrong, no one else in the first round spotted it and having a read of the wiki page is a good advice...

Answer (score 0):

Use `bindValue` instead of `bindParam`, because you are binding value, not parameter. Call `bindValue` after `prepare` statement:

```
...
$name = $_POST['food'];

// Insert user input into table
$STH = $DBH->prepare("INSERT INTO foods ( name ) VALUES ( :name )");
$STH->bindValue(':name', $name);

$result = $DBH->query($STH);
...
```

Comment: I'm no longer receiving a server error, but now when I examine my table, that input does not appear.  my php code is connected to an html form.  I'll edit my code so you can see.  Not sure if that has anything to do with the problem though...